Is there any method to convert vite-ssg javascript file to Shift_JIS encoding
I'm building application using Vue 3, Vite and Vite-SSG for static files generation.
When I built using Vite-SSG, the dist folder is encoded with UTF-8 (or ASCII).
I need to have all my static files (or at least HTML and JS files) to be encoded in Shift_JIS. Currently I convert all files in dist folder to Shift JIS using iconv-lite, but only HTML files are converted to Shift JIS, JS files remained UTF-8 encoded.
I have tried using other encoding library like encoding-japanese, but it didnt work with ASCII encoded files. (Vite-SSG built files are encoded with ASCII)
I have also tried using Astro to build the site (with client:load directive). The built site using Astro was partially hydrated so the parts that were not hydrated will show proper text instead of ???. The built site using Vite-SSG was fully hydrated and all of the text on screen was ???.
Here is my current code to convert all files from UTF-8 (or ASCII) to Shift JIS
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import iconv from "iconv-lite";
import jschardet from "jschardet";
import encode from "encoding-japanese";

function convertFileToJis(filePath, isJsFile = false) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    const content = data.toString("utf8");
    const updatedData = isJsFile
      ? content
      : content.replace(/charset\s*=\s*"utf-8"/i, 'charset="shift_jis"');

    // Convert the data to 'Shift_JIS'
    const convertedCode = iconv.encode(updatedData, "Shift_JIS");
    console.log(filePath);
    console.log(
      `before convert ${filePath} ${jschardet.detect(updatedData).encoding}`
    );
    console.log(
      `after convert ${filePath} ${jschardet.detect(convertedCode).encoding}`
    );

    const relativePath = path.relative("./dist", filePath);
    const newFilePath = path.join("./dist-jis", relativePath);

    fs.mkdirSync(path.dirname(newFilePath), { recursive: true });

    fs.writeFile(newFilePath, convertedCode, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  });
}

function readFiles(dirPath) {
  const entries = fs.readdirSync(dirPath, { withFileTypes: true });

  for (let entry of entries) {
    const fullPath = path.join(dirPath, entry.name);
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
      readFiles(fullPath);
    } else {
      convertFileToJis(fullPath, entry.name.endsWith(".js"));
    }
  }
}

readFiles("./dist");

